# Execute command in terminal an don't wait its return

Tags: 14.04, command-line

I need to run Firefox browser from terminal. Browser works fine, but terminal still waits for Firefox to return and if I do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it terminates Firefox. How to run command to make Firefox work independently from terminal?

Comment: Just add an ampersand sign at the end of the command. This is shell basics...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox 35 on Ubuntu 14.04 detaches itself from the shell, still printing errors though, to eliminate that output, try:

```
firefox >/dev/null 2>&1 www.google.com &
```

The
 `>/dev/null` makes firefox's 'stdout' text stream be sent to "nowhere",
 `2>&1` makes 'stderr' be sent to the same place,
 `&` detaches firefox from the shell.

With Bash "job control" of a long running process, e.g. find on `/` as in:

```
find -printf "%p\n" / >$HOME/LIST-OF-FILES.txt
```

... at any time before it finishes, you can do this:
Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hit <kbd>Z</kbd>

```
[1]+  Stopped                 find ...
```

will be printed and the shell prompt will reappear...
type `bg` and press enter to have find continue run in the background.
Note that errors and warnings will still be printed, as in...

```
find: /run/lightdm: Permission denied
```

To stop those from appearing, add `2>/dev/null` to the command line.

Another alternative to launch GUI based software is

```
xdg-open firefox ...
```

... this is more equal to actually clicking on an icon in your OS.

NOTE: Ubuntu. There are various variants of this for other Linux-variants, and MacOS.

Look up "job control" in http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html - for more info.

Comment: This works fine - I can work with firefox and terminal. But if I close terminal firefox is also killed. How to solve this?

Comment: Check addition above, I hope it will help you - not checked.

Answer (score 5):

Use

`firefox &`

It will create firefox process in background and you can work in terminal

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is what you're looking for and then afterwards type `bg` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Alternatively (but you'll take a bit of getting used to it) is typing `firefox&` instead of `firefox`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> `bg` <kbd>Enter</kbd>